# Evaluate two conditionals for content

Tags: conditionals, ifelse

I have a page where I want to display either a featured image or an image gallery in the left corner of a text block, which wraps around the image.  Pretty basic.

If I use just a single image for the story, I have a class that shows a border around the image. If I decide to use a gallery (via a grid field), the images rotate, and the user can click on them to view larger versions.  Also pretty simple.

The complication is evaluating whether either of the two is empty, and if so, show the one that has content. Further, if neither the gallery or single image have any content, show nothing.

I attached my code in Image1
You can also view an [example here](https://sciannahall.usm.edu/about/lofty-return) of the gallery, and [HERE](https://sciannahall.usm.edu/give-back) of what a single image is supposed to look like (second link is not coded, only "About" template is).  The main "About" link is where I have a single image uploaded, but does not show.

Thank you all for any help you can give!!

[image: Gallery and Single Image code with conditionals]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to check for the [`total_rows`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/grid.html#total-rows) variable?

```
{if gallery_section:total_rows > 0}
    {gallery_section}
        [...]
    {/gallery_section}
{if:elseif about_image_single}
    [...]
{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I had no idea that was an option. I'll try it as soon as I get back home.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, and now the grid doesn't output anything.  It's as if there are no entries in the grid field, even though there are.  See [Gallery page](https://sciannahall.usm.edu/about/lofty-return), but it returns the single image fine, [HERE](https://sciannahall.usm.edu/about)

Comment: Please, try `>= 1`

Comment: Still nothing.  I do have content in the gallery, and NO content in the single image, but the code is parsing as if there is nothing there at all...  I just don't understand why.  I just commented out the If statements and single image just to make sure the gallery still works, and it does.  Just not with the conditionals.  The single image works though.

Comment: Strange, strange... Please, take a look at [this](http://www.blue-dreamer.co.uk/blog/entry/expressionengine-displaying-no-results-for-the-grid-fieldtype), [this](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20629/multiple-instances-of-a-grid-field-pair-in-a-tag-can-trigger-a-conditional-) and [this](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20621/variables-with-modifiers-not-working-in-conditionals-without-braces).

Comment: THANK YOU so much!  I tried a few options, and finally came up with this:  {if '{gallery_section:total_rows}' >= '1'}  Everything seems to work correctly now.  That was the only statement that I had to change in order to get this working.